# Symfony Authenticator error inside PHPStan

Tags: php, symfony, phpstan

I have the following problem. When I run analyse on my src folder, I get this error

```
 ------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Line   Security/CustomerAuthenticator.php
 ------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  38     Parameter #1 $userIdentifier of class Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge constructor expects string, bool|float|int|string given.
  39     Parameter #1 $password of class Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\PasswordCredentials constructor expects string, bool|float|int|string given.
  41     Parameter #2 $csrfToken of class Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\CsrfTokenBadge constructor expects string|null, bool|float|int|string|null given.
  53     Cannot call method getRoles() on Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface|null.
```

The main problem is, that I didn't wrote the Authenticator, so did Symfony. I used maker bundle to make user, and authenticator, and I barely changed anything inside code (I only added supports method, otherwise authenticator wouldn't work)

CustomerAuthenticator

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\CsrfTokenBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\PasswordCredentials;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class CustomerAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $username = $request->request->get('username', '');

        $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $username);

        return new Passport(
            new UserBadge($username),
            new PasswordCredentials($request->request->get('password', '')),
            [
                new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $request->request->get('_csrf_token')),
            ]
        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        $user = $token->getUser();
        if (in_array('ROLE_ADMIN', $user->getRoles(), true)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('admin.adminpanel'));
        }

        // For example:
        // return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('some_route'));
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_home'));
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }

    public function supports(Request $request): bool
    {
        return self::LOGIN_ROUTE === $request->attributes->get('_route')
               && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too strict level in phpstan? What did you expect from boilerplate code? =)
Phpstan says, what's wrong. On line 38 you pass `$username` variable, which you get from request. But it can be not only string in request, what phpstan says. Cast to string, or maybe better - check if that string. Phpstan smart enough to realize, that it's exactly `string` after check. Same with others. Normally that's not a big issue and in most cases it would work as expected. But better to fix all phpstan issues on level at least 7.

For example:

```
$username = (string)$request->request->get('username', '');
```

or

```
if (!is_string($request->request->get('_csrf_token'))) {
    throw new AuthenticationException(''); // or maybe csrf token exception
}
```

Comment: I casted to the string actually, and now works! Thanks for your time, and help!